# Symfony2 one to one relationship form

Tags: forms, symfony

I need some help to understand what I'm doing wrong, I've tried to search one answer here, but nothing work.

here my problem..

I have two entities with a one-to-one relationship:

```
...
class FarmInfo
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="areaCovered", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $areaCovered;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totalIrrigatedArea", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalIrrigatedArea;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="totalStaff", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalStaff;

    /**
     * @var DairyInfo
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="DairyInfo", mappedBy="farmInfo", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $dairyInfo;

    ...
}
```

and

```
...
class DairyInfo
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var FarmInfo
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FarmInfo", inversedBy="dairyInfo", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="farmInfoId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * 
     */
    private $farmInfo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="peakCowMilked", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $peakCowMilked;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cowsMilkedInWinter", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cowsMilkedInWinter;

    ...
}
```

here the formTypes:

```
class FarmInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('areaCovered');
        $builder->add('totalIrrigatedArea');
        $builder->add('totalStaff');

        $builder->add('dairyInfo', new DairyInfoType());
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FOO\CoreBundle\Entity\FarmInfo'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foo_corebundle_farminfo';
    }
}

class DairyInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('peakCowMilked');
        $builder->add('cowsMilkedInWinter');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FOO\CoreBundle\Entity\DairyInfo'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foo_corebundle_dairyinfo';
    }
}
```

That create the form for me with the FarmInfo and the DairyInfo in the same form as I want, but when I persist, FarmInfo persist ok and the DairyInfo persist all fields but the farmInfoId is always null:

```
+---------------+--------------------+------------+
| peakCowMilked | cowsMilkedInWinter | farmInfoId |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+
|            11 |                 11 |       NULL |
+---------------+--------------------+------------+
```

What do I have to do to symfony get this Id automatically ?

Thank you all for advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't show your methods but I am fairly certain you have:

```
class FarmInfo
{
    setDairyInfo($dairyInfo)
    {
        $this->dairyInfo = $dairyInfo;
    }
}
```

The problem is that nothing is setting farmInfo in your dairyInfo class.  So modify setDairyInfo to:

```
    setDairyInfo($dairyInfo)
    {
        $this->dairyInfo = $dairyInfo;
        $dairyInfo->setFarmInfo($this);
    }
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! that was the problem! I was trying everything and was something so simple.

Comment: I cant give you points for your answer because I dont have enough reputation, but you helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem.  This is actually a very common issue.  Just not something that is easy to google for.

Comment: Thank you. Solved a problem for me and someone else I'm working with at the same time. I thought the forms would have automagically worked out the association and couldn't work out why it wouldn't save the relation.

Comment: I have the same issue, but i couldn't fix it with this answer. It's like my setAddress function never was executed. Actually i remove the function and still save data in address table but with "customer_id" NULL